# Is there a way to pass/inject test parameters from outside

Tags: python, python-unittest

Lets say I have the following test class in a tests.py:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls, ip="11.111.111.111",
                   browserType="Chrome",
                   port="4444",
                   h5_client_url="https://somelink.com/",
                   h5_username="username",
                   h5_password="pass"):

        cls.driver = get_remote_webdriver(ip, port, browserType)
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.h5_client_url = h5_client_url
        cls.h5_username = h5_username
        cls.h5_password = h5_password

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()

    def test_01(self):
        # test code

    def test_02(self):
        # test code

    ...

    def test_N(self):
        # test code
```

All my tests (test_01 to test_N) use the parameters, provided in the `setUpClass`. Those parameters have default values:

```
ip="11.111.111.111",
browserType="Chrome",
port="4444",
h5_client_url="https://somelink.com/",
h5_username="username",
h5_password="pass"
```

So I wonder if I can inject new values for those parameters. And I want to do it from another python script so there will be no changes or just minor changes to code of the tests.

Note: I want to run my tests by a batch/shell command and save the output of the test to a log file (to redirect the standard output to that log file)

One think I did was to create a function decorator, that passes a dictionary with `key=parameter_name` and `value=parameter_new_value`, but I had to write to much additional code in the tests.py:

1. I defined the function_decorator logic
2. I put that @function_decorator annotation above every function I want to decorate
3. That function decorator needs that dictionary as a parameter, so I made a main, that looks something like that:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       # terminal command to run tests should look like this /it is executed by the run-test PARROT command/
       #     python [this_module_name] [dictionary_containing_parameters] [log_file.log] *[tests]
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
       # add testbeds_folder as scripts' first parameter, test_log_file as second and tests as the rest
       parser.add_argument('dictionary_containing_parameters')
       parser.add_argument('test_log_file')
       parser.add_argument('unittest_args', nargs='*')

       args = parser.parse_args()

       dictionary_containing_parameters = sys.argv[1]
       test_log_file = sys.argv[2]

       # removes the "dictionary_containing_parameters" and "test_log_file" from sys.args - otherwise an error occurs unittest TestRunner
       sys.argv[1:] = args.unittest_args

       # executes the test/tests and save the output to the test_log_file
       with open(test_log_file, "w") as f:
           runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f)
           unittest.main(defaultTest=sys.argv[1:], exit=False, testRunner=runner)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

You run your test from a different module this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testbed_dict = {"ip": "11.111.111.112",
                    "browserType": "Chrome",
                    "port": "4444",
                    "h5_client_url": "https://new_somelink.com/",
                    "h5_username": "new_username",
                    "h5_password": "new_pass"}

    sys.argv.append(testbed_dict)

    from your_tests_module import *

    with open("test.log", "w") as f:
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f)

        unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]], defaultTest='test_class.test_name', exit=False, testRunner=runner)
```

You can nottice that `argv=[sys.argv[0]]` in `unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]], defaultTest='test_class.test_name', exit=False, testRunner=runner)`. Doing that you change the unittests argument to one (no error occurs) to a list with your real arguments. Note that at the end of this list is the dictionary with the new values of test parameters.

Ok, now you write an function decorator, that should look like this:

```
def load_params(system_arguments_list):
    def decorator(func_to_decorate):
        @wraps(func_to_decorate)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs = system_arguments_list[-1]

            return func_to_decorate(self, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And use this decorator this way:

```
@classmethod
@load_params(sys.argv)
def setUpClass(cls, ip="11.111.111.111",
                   browserType="Chrome",
                   port="4444",
                   h5_client_url="https://somelink.com/",
                   h5_username="username",
                   h5_password="pass"):

cls.driver = get_remote_webdriver(ip, port, browserType)
            cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            cls.h5_client_url = h5_client_url
            cls.h5_username = h5_username
```